# Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service when using GeneticSharp

Tags: c#, threadpool, genetic-algorithm, geneticsharp

Long story short, I'm using GeneticSharp for an iterative/conditional reinforcement learning algorithm. This means that I'm making a bunch of different GeneticAlgorithm instances, each using a shared SmartThreadPool. Only one GA is running at a time though.

After a few iterations of my algorithm, I run into this error, which happens when attempting to start the SmartThreadPool.

Is there any obvious reason this should be happening? I've tried using a different STPE and disposing of it each time, but that didn't seem to help either. Is there some manual cleanup I need to be doing in between each GA run? Should I be using one shared GA instance?

Edit: Quick code sample

```
static readonly SmartThreadPoolTaskExecutor Executor = new SmartThreadPoolTaskExecutor() { MinThreads = 2, MaxThreads = 8 };

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var achromosome = new AChromosome();
    var bchromosome = new BChromosome();

    while(true)
    {
        achromosome = FindBestAChromosome(bchromosome);
        bchromosome = FindBestBChromosome(achromosome);

        // Log results;
    }
}

public static AChromosome FindBestAChromosome(BChromosome chromosome)
{
    AChromosome result;

    var selection = new EliteSelection();
    var crossover = new UniformCrossover();
    var mutation = new UniformMutation(true);
    using (var fitness = new AChromosomeFitness(chromosome))
    {
        var population = new Population(50, 70, chromosome);
        var ga = new GeneticAlgorithm(population, fitness, selection, crossover, mutation);
        ga.Termination = new GenerationNumberTermination(100);
        ga.GenerationRan += LogGeneration;
        ga.TaskExecutor = Executor;
        ga.Start();

        LogResults();
        result = ga.BestChromosome as AChromosome;

        ga.GenerationRan -= LogGeneration;
    }

    return result;
}

public static BChromosome FindBestBChromosome(AChromosome chromosome)
{
    BChromosome result;

    var selection = new EliteSelection();
    var crossover = new UniformCrossover();
    var mutation = new UniformMutation(true);
    using (var fitness = new BChromosomeFitness(chromosome))
    {
        var population = new Population(50, 70, chromosome);
        var ga = new GeneticAlgorithm(population, fitness, selection, crossover, mutation);
        ga.Termination = new GenerationNumberTermination(100);
        ga.GenerationRan += LogGeneration;
        ga.TaskExecutor = Executor;
        ga.Start();

        LogResults();
        result = ga.BestChromosome as BChromosome;

        ga.GenerationRan -= LogGeneration;
    }

    return result;
}
```

AChromosome and BChromosome are each fairly simple, a couple doubles and ints and maybe a function pointer (to a static function).

Edit2: Full call stack with replaced bottom two entries

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle..ctor(Boolean initialState, eventResetMode mode, string name)
    at Amib.Threading.SmartThreadPool..ctor()
    at GeneticSharp.Infrastructure.Threading.SmartThreadPoolTaskExecutor.Start()
    at GeneticSharp.Domain.GeneticAlgorithm.EvaluateFitness()
    at GeneticSharp.Domain.GeneticAlgorithm.EndCurrentGeneration()
    at GeneticSharp.Domain.GeneticAlgorithm.EvolveOneGeneration()
    at GeneticSharp.Domain.GeneticAlgorithm.Resume()
    at GeneticSharp.Domain.GeneticAlgorithm.Start()
    at MyProject.Program.FindBestAChromosome(BChromosome chromosome)
    at MyProject.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Edit3: One last thing to note is that my fitness functions are pretty processing-intensive and one run can take almost 2g of ram (running on a machine with 16g, so no worries there). I've seen no problems with garbage collection though.

So far, this only happens after about 5 iterations (which takes multiple hours).

Comment: How many threads are you using in SmartThreadPoolTaskExecutor (MinThreads e MaxThreads properties)?

Comment: 2 MinThreads, 8 MaxThreads.

Comment: Well, it's a basic set and it's ok. Can you, please, show your code? Feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp/.

Comment: Showing code is harder to do. I'll make a run at a good facsimile.

Comment: @giacomelli Added a quick code sample. I left out the chromosomes themselves, as they're pretty simple. One thing to note is that the fitness function is disposable to make sure that it releases its references to prevent circular dependencies and allow garbage collection.

Comment: It is a low-level operating system error, ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES, usually caused by kernel memory pool exhaustion.   Not so sure how "smart" these kind of libraries are at generating good diagnostics when the chips are down.  But clearly there's no reasonable clue to the underlying problem from your code snippet.  Fwiw, these kind of very expensive computational algorithms do *not* belong on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Is there a better way to divide the work up between multiple cores? Should I just implement my own TaskExecutor which uses the TPL?

Comment: I ran the snippet, using stubs chromosomes and fitness, more than 500 iterations, no memory problem occurred. Is your project built in x64? Is there any unmanaged code on chromosome/fitness?

Comment: Yes built in x64. No unmanaged code. In the full run I watched, it was capped at about 2g of ram. There are 10g free ram available, so it seems logical that after 5 iterations there would be issue. I watched it closely after 1 and there didn't seem to be any memory retention issues though (memory usage dropped down to below 60m between runs), so I don't know if that's the cause.

Comment: After watching the usage some more, I noted that I'm making about 300 handles/second in the first phase and potentially more in the second. Could this be related to the issue? Potentially related to [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx).

Comment: That looks like it may be it! Based on my calculations, 16,777,000/300/3600 (handles/second * seconds/hour) = 15.5. So after 15.5 hours, it will die, which seems to be in line with my findings! Now to research why it's not releasing the handles.

Comment: It looks like I found a memory leak deep in one of our libraries. While the bulk of our objects were being GCd away just fine, some small ones were hanging on and holding their handles. This made it seem like there was no issue (after GC, it dropped almost all memory used), but did become an issue over time! I'm testing a solution right now and if it works, I'll post it as an answer. Thanks both of you for the help!

Comment: That didn't seem to be it. I've optimized the memory usage to hell, so now my program is constantly using under 35MB, even during the more intense step. It's *still* taking system handles though. Maintains gaining about 300/s and doesn't release them until closing. I've been monitoring the memory usage through Telerik's JustTrace and there are only about 20-25k objects in my app after a few hours running, but still it easily reaches into the hundreds of thousands of handles. The error in the stack trace pointed to SmartThreadPool. Could that not be disposing of EventWaitHandles properly?

Comment: Try to use population.GenerationStrategy = new PerformanceGenerationStrategy (). This will keep only the last generation inside the GA.

Comment: I'll give that a try. So in another thread I posted (but forgot to here) that it appears that it was my antivirus preventing the threads from finalizing. I was just making them too fast for it to handle them properly. I tried it in a VM with MSE and it worked fine. I'll have to try it with that solution and see if it improves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was my antivirus preventing the threads from finalizing. Now I'm running it on a machine with a different antivirus and it's running just fine. If I come up with a better answer for how to handle this in the future, I'll update here.